# Catalina Messages app: run applescript on receive new message & when the message is read?

Tags: applescript, messages, catalina

Are applescripts for Messages still saved in /Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.iChat?  That seems like an odd location, but I didn't find a folder for com.apple.messages

I tried saving this in the com.apple.iChat folder, but nothing happened:

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received
        display dialog "testing"
    end message received
end using terms from
```

Comment: **AppleScript** _handler_ support was removed from **Messages** in **macOS High Sierra 10.13.4**.

Comment: Does that mean there's no way to have a script run when a message is received?  I suppose I could try using a watched folder to keep track of when the chat.db-wal file gets opened.  It seems to get opened whenever Messages receives a new message and when the message is read.

Comment: Watching the _file/folder_ will only let you know the _state_ of it has changed, not what the change was. I'd assume it's possible to determine through an `sqlite3` _query_ what actually changed in the database and what the change was.

Comment: You're right.  I mistakenly assumed there would be a way to have an applescript check if unread messages exist.  Apparently not.

Comment: You might find this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086287/reading-imessages-with-applescript interesting.

Comment: Ugh.  I came up with a workaround, but boy is it ridiculous.  Watched folder: when the file is updated, run an applescript.  As part of the script, check to see if Messages app is frontmost.  If it's not frontmost, I've got new messages.  If it IS frontmost, that's me reading messages.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Jared, which is an iMessage Chat Bot: https://github.com/ZekeSnider/Jared

There's a sample plugin in the repository, yet this requires some Xcode knowledge.

It seems Apple removed the handler because they launched iMessage for Business https://developer.apple.com/business-chat/. If you look into the API, there‘s a „Message received“ handler, so it may be possible using that service, but probably not a good idea for personal stuff.

Edit2:
Back to the SQL solution, this article dives pretty deep in explaining: https://stmorse.github.io/journal/iMessage.html

Edit3:
I found the following repositories based on nodejs :
https://github.com/CamHenlin/imessageclient
https://github.com/CamHenlin/imessagebot

Comment: +1  Great answer!   Business chat is actually a server (cloud) technology similar to Alexa, Watson, and Cortana (being pushed back from consumer to business)

Comment: Also, messages are stored in a sqlite database...maybe you could monitor that database for changes and respond accordingly?  Though that's getting into a software development question.

Comment: Check my updated answer, this is pretty useful: https://stmorse.github.io/journal/iMessage.html